# Why are my Slick Slider carousels creating an additional dot and slide, when there is no content to suggest so?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I am slightly baffled by these two sliders I am setting up. Why are they both getting an additional blank slide created?

I have previously had numerous sliders on the same page and this is the first I am seeing of them creating there own slides.

I pull in the content from the blog posts, using a wp_query. This works successfully with no extra content created when there is no initiating js for the sliders.

**EDIT** (Rephrasing and adding more detail as original question maybe wasn't clear) :

I initiate two sliders, these sliders are initiated and successfully become sliders, however both are created with an extra slide at the end of each slide list. These slides should not be there and the data they are pulling through contains one less index that what is shown by the slider, meaning both sliders have a blank slide (if there are 6 records in the back-end it will show 7 slides).

**Please can someone help me prevent this additional slide from showing?**

```
<div class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4 px3 mb3 sm:mb4 lg:mb0">
    <h3 class="h2 md:h1 extra-bold uppercase mt0 mb0">Events</h3>

    <?php
    $latest_events = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    )); ?>

    <?php if( $latest_events->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <ul id="events-slider" class="news-events-slider list-reset mt0 mb0">
            <?php while( $latest_events->have_posts() ) : $latest_events->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                $event_title        = get_the_title();
                $event_start_date   = get_field('event_start_date');
                $event_end_date     = get_field('event_end_date');
                $event_location     = get_field('event_location');
                $event_excerpt      = excerpt(55);
                $event_link         = get_the_permalink(); ?>
                <li class="event-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2">
                    <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0">
                        <?php echo $event_title ?>
                    </h4>
                    <p class="primary uppercase mt0 mb0">
                        <?php echo $event_start_date; ?>
                        <?php if( $event_end_date ) : ?> - <?php echo $event_end_date; ?><?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if( $event_location ) : ?>
                            <span style="position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0 3px;">|</span> 
                            <?php echo $event_location; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="h5 mt1">
                        <?php echo $event_excerpt; ?>
                    </p>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <ul>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>No events</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4 px3 mb3 sm:mb4 lg:mb0">
    <h3 class="h2 md:h1 extra-bold uppercase mt0 mb0">News</h3>

    <?php
    $latest_news = new WP_Query( array(
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    )); ?>

    <?php if( $latest_news->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <ul id="news-slider" class="news-events-slider list-reset mt0 mb0">
            <?php while( $latest_news->have_posts() ) : $latest_news->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                // $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                // $post_thumbnail_alt = get_post_meta($post_thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                // $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )[0];
                $article_title = get_the_title();
                $article_date = get_the_date( get_option('data_format') );
                $article_excerpt = excerpt(11);
                // $post_time = get_post_time( 'g:i a' );
                $article_link = get_the_permalink(); ?>
                <li class="news-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2">
                    <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0">
                        <a href="<?php echo $article_link; ?>" class="primary">
                        <?php echo $article_title ?>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                    <p class="uppercase mt0 mb0">
                        <?php echo $article_date; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="h5 mt1">
                        <?php echo $article_excerpt; ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $article_link; ?>" class="btn btn-outline primary h6 uppercase py1 mb1">
                    View more
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <ul>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>No news</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I then initiate the sliders using these snips of js:

```
<script>
    $('#news-slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 1
    });
    $('#events-slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 1
    });
</script>
```

I then get the unexpected result of the last slide that completely shouldn't be there, showing up as a blank slide :(

Like this attached image:

[image: Blank Slide Screenshot]

Output code:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap mxn3">
    <div class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4 px3 mb3 sm:mb4 lg:mb0" role="toolbar">
        <h3 class="h2 md:h1 extra-bold uppercase mt0 mb0">Events</h3>
        <ul id="events-slider" class="news-events-slider list-reset mt0 mb0 slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted">
            <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
                <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 2520px; transform: translate3d(-2160px, 0px, 0px);" role="listbox">
                    <li class="event-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide10">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> ITM Poland 2020</h4>
                        <p class="primary uppercase mt0 mb0"> June 2                                         - June 5 <span style="position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0 3px;">|</span> Poznan Congress Center, Poland</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> Example will be exhibiting at ITM Poland on the 2nd – 5th June 2020 at the Poznan Congress Center.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="event-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide11">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> Fabtech 2020</h4>
                        <p class="primary uppercase mt0 mb0"> November 18                                        - November 20 <span style="position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0 3px;">|</span> Las Vegas Convention Center, Las Vegas, NV 89109, USA</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> Example will be exhibiting at Fabtech, Las Vegas, on the 18th to 20th June 2020 at the Las Vegas Convention Center, 3150 Paradise Road, Las Vegas, NV 89109, USA &nbsp;</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="event-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide12">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> Beijing Essen Welding &amp; Cutting Fair</h4>
                        <p class="primary uppercase mt0 mb0"> June 2                                         - June 5 <span style="position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0 3px;">|</span> Shenzhen World Exhibition &amp; Convention Center, Shenzhen, China</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> Example will be exhibiting at Beijing Essen Welding &amp; Cutting Fair on the 2nd – 5th June 2020 at the Shenzhen World Exhibition &amp; Convention Center, Shenzhen, China</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="event-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide13">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> TWI 2020</h4>
                        <p class="primary uppercase mt0 mb0"> June 4 <span style="position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0 3px;">|</span> Granta Centre, TWI Ltd, Cambridge, UK</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> Example will be exhibiting at TWI, the UK and Joining Exhibition on the June 4th 2020 at the Granta Centre, TWI Ltd, Great Abington, Cambridge.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="event-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide14">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> EXPOWELDING 2020</h4>
                        <p class="primary uppercase mt0 mb0"> October 13                                         - October 15 <span style="position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0 3px;">|</span> Expo Silesia, 41219 Sosnowiec, Poland</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> Example will be exhibiting at the ExpoWelding, Sosnowiec, Poland on the 13th to 15th October 2020 at the Expo Silesia, Braci Mieroszewskich 124, 41219 Sosnowiec, Silesia, Poland</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="event-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="5" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide15">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> METALEX 2020</h4>
                        <p class="primary uppercase mt0 mb0"> November 18                                        - November 21 <span style="position: relative; top: -1px; margin: 0 3px;">|</span> Bangkok International Trade &amp; Exhibition Centre</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> Example will be exhibiting at Metalex, Bangkok, Thailand on the 18th to 21st November 2020 at the Bangkok International Trade &amp; Exhibition Centre, 88 Debaratana Rd, แขวง บางนาใต้ Bang Na, Bangkok, Thailand</p>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="6" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 400px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide16"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="slick-dots" style="" role="tablist">
                <li class="" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="navigation10" id="slick-slide10"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">1</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation11" id="slick-slide11"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">2</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation12" id="slick-slide12"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">3</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation13" id="slick-slide13"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">4</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation14" id="slick-slide14"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">5</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation15" id="slick-slide15"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">6</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="false" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation16" id="slick-slide16" class="slick-active"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">7</button></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-4 px3 mb3 sm:mb4 lg:mb0" role="toolbar">
        <h3 class="h2 md:h1 extra-bold uppercase mt0 mb0">News</h3>
        <ul id="news-slider" class="news-events-slider list-reset mt0 mb0 slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted">
            <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
                <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 1080px; transform: translate3d(-720px, 0px, 0px);" role="listbox">
                    <li class="news-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> <a href="https://www.camvaceng.com/chinese-office-now-open/" class="primary" tabindex="-1"> Chinese office now open </a></h4>
                        <p class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> March 17, 2020</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> Chinese office now open – Incorporation of Aquasium Technology (Beijing) Co.…</p>
                        <a href="https://www.camvaceng.com/chinese-office-now-open/" class="btn btn-outline primary h6 uppercase py1 mb1" tabindex="-1"> View more </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="news-slide border-top border-white pt2 mt2 slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 360px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide01">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> <a href="https://www.camvaceng.com/revolutionary-new-beam-welding-technology-set-to-fast-track-large-manufacturing-projects/" class="primary" tabindex="-1"> Revolutionary New Beam Welding Technology Set To Fast-Track Large Manufacturing Projects </a></h4>
                        <p class="uppercase mt0 mb0"> April 12, 2019</p>
                        <p class="h5 mt1"> A new technology could improve the efficiency of large-scale manufacturing projects…</p>
                        <a href="https://www.camvaceng.com/revolutionary-new-beam-welding-technology-set-to-fast-track-large-manufacturing-projects/" class="btn btn-outline primary h6 uppercase py1 mb1" tabindex="-1"> View more </a>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 400px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide02"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="slick-dots" style="" role="tablist">
                <li class="" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="navigation00" id="slick-slide00"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">1</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation01" id="slick-slide01"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">2</button></li>
                <li aria-hidden="false" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation02" id="slick-slide02" class="slick-active"><button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">3</button></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could help me debug this, the client is really pushing hard on this and I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The code uses 'ul' tags however they are not closed. This is the route of the issue.

You must make sure the element you are targeting with the .slick() function, is closed in the appropriate place.

This will prevent additional blank slides being create by Slick.